# Global Search and Replace throughout Flex Project files?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

Is there a way to do a search and replace across multiple files in a single project?

thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ctrl+Shift+F -> Enter 'Containing text', select 'Enclosing projects', Click 'Replace' button, enter replacement text.

Answer (score 0):

Also, check out [Windows Grep](http://www.wingrep.com/).  It does not validate your changes to make sure no errors were created from them.  But, it is a good way of doing exactly what you want without being tied to an IDE.